# Iphone WebView links won't open in Safari

Tags: iphone, mobile, xcode4

I have followed many tutorials and my links in my web view are still not opening up in safari.
I am a noob, this is my first IPhone App, so I hope I'm just missing something simple.

```
 //
//  ViewController.m
//  FirstIphoneApp
//
//  Created by admin on 12/2/11.
//  Copyright (c) 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize webView;

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[inRequest URL]];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://somewebsite.com/iphone.html"]]];


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}

@end
```

And here is my Header File

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate,UIAlertViewDelegate>{
   IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
}


@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the shouldStartLoadWithRequest method fire? It may be that you haven't connected the delegate in your nib file. Usually this will be connected to your view controller, or whatever file the shouldStartLoadWithRequest method is found in.

Comment: Ah, yes I set a breakpoint and it doesn't seem to be getting hit. I don't see a nib file, is that the "storyboard" file in XCode 4.2.1? and can you provide any instruction on connecting the delegate in the storyboard?

Comment: I was able to locate the delegate. I had selected the View instead of the View Controller as the Delegate. It works! Thanks